# Is it legit for elements to appear after </html>?

Tags: html

[Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example) recommend us to defer loading of secondary stylesheets by placing them after the closing `</html>` tag. Code example from that page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .blue{color:blue;}
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="blue">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="deferred_stylesheet.css">
```

This strikes me as odd, because I would expect Google to recommend standard practices instead of *non-standard* practices.

Is the code above *legit*? Do the HTML5 standards provide consistent rules for browsers to parse these sort of code?

**What problems will we** (or our users in fact) **encounter** if we use the tags as such?

Comment: The only problem I can think of is that it won't validate. Aside from that though, I think you're fine. Oddly enough, I have never seen Google follow this advice themselves. I have inspected various pages and even run them through their insight tool..

Comment: The correct place is just before closing html tag.

Comment: You might find **[this article](http://blog.futtta.be/tag/defer-css/)** interesting. In short it sums it up this way: "Deferring all CSS is useless, performance is worse, desktop PageSpeed score is (slightly) lower and there is a “flash of unstyled content” between the rendering of the page and the application of the CSS"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're missing your `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the top, which is required for HTML5 documents.

Second, you're also missing a `<title>` tag in your head.

Finally, no, tags after the closing `</html>` tag are not allowed.  If you run your doc through the [w3 validator service](http://validator.w3.org) you'll see:

> Line 14, Column 54: Stray start tag link.
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="deferred_stylesheet.css">`

This error is unrecoverable.

I would expect to face browsers either totally ignoring it or loading it. Depending on the browser, the version and the platform.  Since you can't be sure it'll work (and since it's non-conforming), you shouldn't do it.

**UPDATE**

This is non-valid HTML, however [user-agents are allowed to parse it and include in the body](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-afterbody). But they are not required to since they can define their own rules for [parse errors](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error)

Comment: So do you mean that the page https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery#example is giving bad advice?

Comment: @Pacerier yes, I do.  If you look at the HTML 5 specification is out of spec to place tags after the closing `</html>` tag. If you want to guarantee that user-agents will correctly parse your document, you should follow the spec. Additional, there is enough crappy non-compliant HTML that people have to deal with every day. The point of HTML5 is to fix that. So lets all agree to follow the spec!

Comment: Btw, didn't HTML5 explicitly state the "parsing rules" to follow when browsers encountered jumbled up tags like those code shown in the question above? So can we say that browsers that follow the HTML5 standard will still parse the above code consistently?

Comment: @Pacerier Sort of. As the [after body](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-afterbody) parsing rule states it is a parser error, so the parser **can** flip back to 'in body' and insert the tag into the document. However, how to handle [parse errors](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error) is left to the user-agent. The user-agent can choose to reject this document since it's non-conforming.

Comment: Thanks, I think that last comment answers the question. You may want to include that into the post.

Answer (score 5):

It **isn't** correct to put anything outside the HTML tags however all browsers try to sort the mess they get served.

Almost all browsers e.g. Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc will sort this out for you. Some self written browsers maybe won't do this.

However you can better write it in between the *head* tag for performance (because then the browsers don't need to sort out the dirty coding).

This means users will encounter almost no problems.

Comment: For varying "quirky" definitions of **try**.

Comment: However it's NOT compliant with the spec and we shouldn't do it. Lets make the web a better place by following specifications correctly so we don't create another IE6, 7, 8 or 9, please!

Answer (score 2):

**Is this correct or even allowed structure?**
No. It is incorrect to place elements outside the `<html>`tag.

**Oh dear! Will it land me in problems?**
No. Browsers will fix your bad code as best as it can. This is no problem for the browser.

**Should I do it?**
Well ... it's complicated. Short answer is "no, probably not". As developers, it is our responsibility to ensure that our code is correct (machines can't be trusted, that will be our downfall!). The rules are there for a reason. On the other hand, as hackers, we can some times break and bend rules, if it makes sense in the situation and you know what the consequenses will be.

**HTML hacking? What the hell are you talking about?**
Browsers will always try to render the document as best as it can. Interestingly, you don't even have to give the a `<html>` tag – the browser will figure it out for you.

Here's an [example page](http://tinybits.dk/labs/zonk/) – inspect the rendered DOM, and the view source. I've almost not given it anything to work with, and it has kindly created all missing tags. Neat! You do need a `DOCTYPE` declaration and in most cases a `<title>` tag.

But, I digress ...

So, the browser will definitely render it correctly. It is, however, incorrect as per the specs, and the document will not validate (if you care about that). For the most part, it's a good idea to follow the specs, unless you have a good reason.

Now, I can't see why Google wants you to place it outside the `<html>` tag. It sounds strange, however I guess they know what they're doing. My guess is, that they want to make absolutely sure, that the ressource is loaded last.

Comment: But when you say "the browser will figure it out", is that behavior a consistent behavior specified by the HTML5 standard?

Comment: No, it's browser vendors making browsers render bad code in a decent way.

Comment: Actually if you read the spec this is untrue. User agents are allowed to [abort document parsing upon a parse error](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error). Placing a tag AFTER the close `</body>` tag is a parse error. So the behavior is specifically defined to be inconsistent.

Comment: It is incorrect structure according to the spec. However, I think you will be extremely hard pressed to find a browser that does not fix your bad code some. The vendors don't want to be those guys who can't correctly display a web page (even if it contains errors), so they accept it and fix it for you, no money up front. Will you face problems? Most certainly not. Should you start cowboy coding and rely on the browser to clean up your HTML? Probably not.

Comment: @Pacerier And yes – I believe someone told me that a document exists, that basically describes best practice for how browsers should treat bad HTML, but I am not certain. Will attempt to investigate.